# How to draw a curve with given ordered points in Matplotlib instead of straight lines

Tags: python, numpy, plot, sympy, nyquist

How to draw a curve with given points using matplotlib -

I am drawing a Nyquist plot so these are basically real and imaginary values of my characteristic equation at various points (omega or w = 0,oo etc.) . So the order is important here.

Points - [0.008,0,-0.047,-0.0000001] and [-1,-0.075,0,0.0000001]

```
x = np.array([0.008,0,-0.047,-0.0000001])

y = np.array([-1,-0.075,0,0.0000001])

plt.plot(x,y)
```

Simply using matplotlib I get:

Instead I want something like this:

Went through many interpolation methods but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: your pictures are missing